# Second order ODE integration using scipy

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I am trying to integrate a second order differential equation using 'scipy.integrate.odeint'. My eqution is as follows

```
m*x[i]''+x[i]'= K/N*sum(j=0 to N)of sin(x[j]-x[i])
```

which I have converted into two first order ODEs as followed. In the below code, yinit is array of the initial values x(0) and x'(0). My question is what should be the values of x(0) and x'(0) ?

```
x'[i]=y[i]
y'[i]=(-y[i]+K/N*sum(j=0 to N)of sin(x[j]-x[i]))/m

from numpy import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint

N = 50 

def f(theta, t):
    global N
    x, y = theta
    m = 0.95
    K = 1.0
    fx = zeros(N, float)
    for i in range(N):  
        s = 0.0 
        for j in range(i+1,N):  
            s = s + sin(x[j] - x[i])  
        fx[i] = (-y[i] + (K*s)/N)/m  
    return array([y, fx])  

t = linspace(0, 10, 100, endpoint=False)
```

Uniformly generating random number

```
theta = random.uniform(-180, 180, N)
```

Integrating function `f` using `odeint`

```
yinit = array([x(0), x'(0)])
y = odeint(f, yinit, t)[:,0]
print (y)
```

Comment: I guess you mean `yinit = array([x(0), x'(0)]`, because these are the initial values. The initial values are the boundary conditions that make the equations solution unique. You should know best which solution you need.

Comment: Yes, you are right initial values are x(0) and x'(0). I have corrected them in question. If I put m=0, then in first order ODE, array theta which I have drawn from Uniform distribution, would be the x(0). Whereas in case of 2 order ODE I know x(0)=theta but how could I find x'(0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose as initial condition whatever you want.

In your case, you decided to use a random initial condition for `x` for all the oscillators. You can use a random initial condition for 'y' as well I guess, as I did below.

There were a few errors in the above code, mostly on how to unpack `x,y` from `theta` and how to repack them at the end (see `concatenate` below in the corrected code). See also the `concatenate` for `yinit`.

The rest are stylish/minor changes.

```
from numpy import concatenate, linspace, random, mod, zeros, sin
from scipy.integrate import odeint

Nosc = 20
assert mod(Nosc, 2) == 0

def f(theta, _):
    N = theta.size / 2
    x, y = theta[:N], theta[N:]
    m = 0.95
    K = 1.0
    fx = zeros(N, float)
    for i in range(N):
        s = 0.0
        for j in range(i + 1, N):
            s = s + sin(x[j] - x[i])
        fx[i] = (-y[i] + (K * s) / N) / m
    return concatenate(([y, fx]))

t = linspace(0, 10, 50, endpoint=False)

theta = random.uniform(-180, 180, Nosc)
theta2 = random.uniform(-180, 180, Nosc) #added initial condition for the velocities of the oscillators

yinit = concatenate((theta, theta2))

res = odeint(f, yinit, t)
X = res[:, :Nosc].T
Y = res[:, Nosc:].T
```

To plot the time evolution of the system, you can use something like

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for displacement in X:
    ax.plot(t, displacement)
ax.set_xlabel('t')
ax.set_ylabel('x')
fig.show()
```

What are you modelling? At first the eq. looked a bit like [kuramoto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuramoto_model#Definition) oscillators, but then I noticed you also have a `x[i]''` term.

Notice how in your model, as you do not have a spring term in the equation, like a term `x(t)` at the LHS, the value of `x` converges to an arbitrary value:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for rectifying my code. I am still not sure is it right to use a random sequence for velocity theta2. Yes, in fact it's Kuramoto equation but with inertia term x''. I removed the natural frequnecy term on the RHS of eqn. just for to look my program simpler. Let me see if it works.

Comment: Why would you then be sure it is right to use a random sequence as initial condition for the displacement and not for the velocity?

Comment: What I meant was theta2(at t=0) is the derivative of theta at (t=0). So, should theta2 not depend on theta? Thanks anyway.

Comment: For one oscillator, displacement and velocity are two distinct degrees of freedom ([DOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom)), and are not related to each other as initial conditions. You are right saying that "theta2(at t=0) is the derivative of theta at (t=0)". But this depends on the previous instant of theta, that can be any arbitrary number and is unknown. And consider accepting the answer/upvoting if you're satisfied with the answer here at SO.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's helpful. Anyway, inside function f(theta,_), I assume Nosc should be used instead of N for the 'for' loops for i and j and where fx is defined.

Comment: They are the same number, `N=Nosc`. Because `yinit` has size `2*Nosc` where it is defined, `yinit` is passed as argument of `f`, and `N=size(argument of f)/2=2*Nosc/2=Nosc`.